# Iterating and Adding a column with user defined Calculations in R

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(hhid = c(5668, 5595, 4724, 4756, 4856, 4730), 
    me = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ls = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), lsn = c("", "", "Goatry", "Goatry", "Goatry", "Goatry"
    ), ag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

For every `hhid`, if there is a 1 in `me` column then a new column is added with name `mt` with value 1000,
else if there is 0 in `me` then it should move to next column to `ls`.

If there is 1 in `ls` and *Goatery* in `lsn` then 150 is new value in column `mt` else if there is `Poultry` then 300 in column `mt`.If there is 0 in `ls` then iterate through next column `ag`.If there is 1 then 600 in `mt`.
So basically iterating through each column for every `hhid` and adding a new column to get a value for every `hhid` as mentioned above.

The expected output in the OP's comment is

```
df2 <-
structure(list(hhid = c(2L, 3L, 1347L, 642L), 
me = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ls = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
lsn = c("", "Goatry", "Poultry", ""), 
ag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), mt = c(1000L, 150L, 300L, 600L)), 
row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: structure(list(hhid = c(2L, 3L, 1347L, 642L), me = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), ls = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), lsn = c("", "Goatry", "Poultry", 
""), ag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), mt = c(1000L, 150L, 300L, 600L)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: The `hhid` in the input is completely different from `df2$hhid`.

Comment: Yes bcoz df2 is the expected output.

Comment: Okay, then explain this: all of your instructions say to set or change `mt`. None of your instructions say to change `hhid`. How is it that `hhid` is mysteriously changed between your input data and your output? Additionally, your expected output has fewer rows than your input. Is there some filtering you are expecting as well?

Comment: None of the hhid is changed.I just picked up couple of ids to show the desired output.You can also find it in the dataset.
Anyways,thanks for the solution.helped a lot......:)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: `mutate` with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(mt = case_when(
    me==1 ~ 1000L,
    me==0 & ls ==1 & lsn=="Goatry" ~ 150L,
    me==0 & ls ==1 & lsn=="Poultry" ~ 300L,
    ls==0 & ag==1 ~ 600L,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_
  ))
```

```
  hhid me ls    lsn ag   mt
1 5668  1  0         0 1000
2 5595  1  0         0 1000
3 4724  0  1 Goatry  0  150
4 4756  0  1 Goatry  0  150
5 4856  0  1 Goatry  0  150
6 4730  0  1 Goatry  0  150
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    unite(mt, me, ls, lsn, remove = FALSE) %>%
    mutate(mt = factor(mt, levels =c("1_0_", "0_1_Goatry", "0_1_"), 
       labels = c("1000", 150, 300)))
```

-output

```
  hhid   mt me ls    lsn ag
1 5668 1000  1  0         0
2 5595 1000  1  0         0
3 4724  150  0  1 Goatry  0
4 4756  150  0  1 Goatry  0
5 4856  150  0  1 Goatry  0
6 4730  150  0  1 Goatry  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that `dplyr::case_when` (or `data.table::fcase`) is the best option here.

Your first and second datasets are not the same, so I'll demonstrate on both.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(mt2 = case_when(
    me == 1                    ~ 1000, 
    ls == 1 & lsn == "Goatry"  ~ 150, 
    ls == 1 & lsn == "Poultry" ~ 300, 
    ls == 0 & ag ==          1 ~ 600)
  )
#   hhid me ls    lsn ag  mt2
# 1 5668  1  0         0 1000
# 2 5595  1  0         0 1000
# 3 4724  0  1 Goatry  0  150
# 4 4756  0  1 Goatry  0  150
# 5 4856  0  1 Goatry  0  150
# 6 4730  0  1 Goatry  0  150
```

Your second (storing in `mt2` for comparison):

```r
df2 %>%
  mutate(mt2 = case_when(
    me == 1                    ~ 1000, 
    ls == 1 & lsn == "Goatry"  ~ 150, 
    ls == 1 & lsn == "Poultry" ~ 300, 
    ls == 0 & ag ==          1 ~ 600)
  )
#   hhid me ls     lsn ag   mt  mt2
# 1    2  1  0          0 1000 1000
# 2    3  0  1  Goatry  0  150  150
# 3 1347  0  1 Poultry  0  300  300
# 4  642  0  0          1  600  600
```